# The ACF of a unit root process

Tags: forecasting, autocorrelation, unit-root

If the correlogram of $Y_t$ displays slow decay (i.e., non-stationarity), is this indicative of a unit root? I reasoned that for the model $Y_t = Y_{t-1} + u_t$, the ACF is equal to 1 for all lags, and therefore, the answer to my question is yes. But I just want to be sure.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but there are also various tests for that. Regards, -A

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  If you want to make sure that its unit root here, you can use 
Dickey-Fuller test with
 $$
H_0 \colon \text{the presence of unit root}.  
$$
(thats mean time series is not stationary).

For example, in R:

`library(tseries)

adf.test(YourTimeSeries)`